# use .dir-locals.el to setup blacklist (based on projectile root) for ccls (c++mode server)

Tags: directory-local-variables, ccls, lsp

I use this setup to setup blacklists for ccls in my project:

```
(
(prog-mode (ccls-initialization-options . (:index (:blacklist [
"^/Users/xxx/proj/dir1/"
"^/Users/xxx/proj/dir2/(dir3|dir4)/"])))
)
```

How do I make it dependent on (projectile-project-root) instead?

This didn't work:

```
(
 (nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (require 'projectile)
                   (setq ccls-initialization-options (:index
                                                      (:blacklist
                                                       (vector
    (concat "^" (projectile-project-root) "dir1/")
    (concat "^" (projectile-project-root) "dir2/(dir3|dir4)/"))))))))))
)
```

Comment: "This didn't work" -- You should state *how* it failed, to help people understand the nature of the problem more easily.

Comment: Thanks phill, will do next time. You answered it correctly for this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tangentially, for general usage you should consider whether you need to escape potential regexp-special characters in the value of `(projectile-project-root)`.  For elisp regexps you would pass it through `regexp-quote`, but it's evident that these values are destined for something else, so you might need to do something more custom (or just ignore the issue if you believe you can do so in practice -- there's a *reasonable* chance that a directory path is going to be safe as-is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.

I imagine you want something like this?

```
((nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (require 'projectile)
                   (setq-local ccls-initialization-options
                               `(:index
                                 (:blacklist
                                  ,(vector
                                    (concat "^" (projectile-project-root)
                                            "dir1/")
                                    (concat "^" (projectile-project-root)
                                            "dir2/(dir3|dir4)/"))))))))))
```